# LIKE - Can't use the %%s% wildcard with MySQL connector

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm new to `mysql.connector`.
I'm trying to query my database using the LIKE wildcard.
When saving users, we ask them for the languages they speak and make
a string like this: `"en+ru"`, users aren't limited to 2 languages. **When querying, I'm using 1 language i.e: "en" or "ru"**

I would like to find users by location and what language they speak.

This is the function I use to query the database:

```
    def get_users_where_location_langs(self, location, langs):
        get_users_formula = "SELECT * FROM users_cert WHERE location = %s AND langs LIKE %%s%"
        self.cursor.execute(get_cert_formula, (location, langs))
        return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

When executing this function, I recieve the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to y
our MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'en'%' at line 1
```

How would I solve this problem?

Here are some things that I've already tried:

1:

```
    def get_users_where_location_langs(self, location, langs):
        get_cert_formula = "SELECT * FROM users_cert WHERE location = %s AND langs LIKE %{}%".format(langs)
        self.cursor.execute(get_cert_formula, (location, langs))
        return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

I get the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to y
our MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%en%' at line 1
```

2:
replacing the `%%s%` with `*%s*`. I got the same error as the first.

3:

```
get_cert_formula = "SELECT * FROM haverim_cert WHERE location = %s AND langs LIKE %'%s'%"
```

Error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%''en''%' at line 1
```

4:

```
get_cert_formula = "SELECT * FROM haverim_cert WHERE location = %s AND langs LIKE %(%s)%"
```

Error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%('en')%' at line 1
```

5:

```
get_cert_formula = "SELECT * FROM haverim_cert WHERE location = %s AND langs LIKE ('%',%s,'%')"
```

Error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

6:

```
get_cert_formula = "SELECT * FROM haverim_cert WHERE location = %s AND langs LIKE '%%s%'"
```

Error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'en'%'' at line 1
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: _“How would I solve this problem?”_ - by not storing the data in such a messed-up format to begin with. The keyword is _normalization_.

Comment: @CBroe how would you store the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `?` or `%s` placeholders and concatenate the `%` wildcards:

```
get_users_formula = "SELECT * FROM users_cert WHERE location = ? AND langs LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')"
```

or:

```
get_users_formula = "SELECT * FROM users_cert WHERE location = %s AND langs LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%')"
```